# eventlistener and window.onload not working for me

Tags: javascript

I've tried several things to make it work. It worked before when I hosted it all on the same file, but now it won't work when I separated it on my script.js.

this is part of my code

```
var buttonStart = document.getElementById("forward");
var buttonStop = document.getElementById("stop");

buttonStart.addEventListener("click", speedup);

function speedup() {
  clearInterval(Interval);

  speed = speed + 1;

  Interval = setInterval(valuecalc, 1000 / speed);
  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = speed;
};

buttonStop.addEventListener("click", stopspeed);

function stopspeed() {
  clearInterval(Interval);
  speed = 0;
  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = speed;
};

var starts = start();
window.onload = starts;
```

Here's the live demo it's a sort of clicker game I'm working on: https://jobclicker.netlify.app/

This is my error: script.js:35

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
> at script.js:35:17

Comment: I suggest searching for that error, or part of it (say, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null") in the search engine of your choice and read the first page or two of results. The error occurs when something you think is not null or undefined is in fact null or undefined. In this case, likely `buttonStop`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: If you want people to help you solve your problem, please provide some demo code that allows us to reproduce the problem. The code you posted is incomplete, meaning it's missing too much details to allow us to easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: my bad I thought the netlify.app was good enough since it's my code. here's my github of the code in question https://github.com/gonzalocdlp/Rat-Race-Clicker-Game